# Can't use strstr() properly in C

Tags: c, string, glibc

So I'm building a web server in C. I wanna parse the requests using regex but for the moment I thought I'd make something quick to make it work first. Currently, I'm implementing cookies and to find if a request has the cookie field I'm using this.

```
int find_cookie(const char * request){
    char * start_pointer = NULL;
    long ret = 0;

    if ((start_pointer = strstr(request, "Cookie:") != NULL)){
        //Do stuff with the pointer
        //such as using strtol to get the value as a number
        ret = strtol(start_pointer + strlen("Cookie:"), NULL, 10);
    }else return 0;

    return (int) ret;
}
```

Now, one would think that the problem lies on the strtol(). However, after using GDB I noticed that when there's no cookie field, it returns NULL (as expected) but, on the other hand if it's there and I try to print the value of start_pointer, it will print: "Can't access memory address 0x1". What's the matter here? By the way, when I debug the program I can see that the request variable contains the whole request and I added a '\0' at the end.

Comment: You have not passed enough arguments to `strtol`.

Comment: it's in the real code, i messed it up when writing it here, sorry

Comment: This is why we *always* ask for [mcve].

Comment: Well, please don't post fake code, or you introduce problems that didn't exist.

Answer (score 3):

You have the order of operations wrong. Try this instead:

```
if ((start_pointer = strstr(request, "Cookie:")) != NULL){
```

Otherwise, you are setting `start_pointer` to the result of the comparison, which is `1` (true).

Comment: That makes so much sense, you're right. Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe even better: don't be smart and use 2 simpler statements instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ((start_pointer = strstr(request, "Cookie:") != NULL)){
```

should be

```
if (((start_pointer = strstr(request, "Cookie:")) != NULL){
```

Notice the change of bracket's location.

Assigment operator `=` has the lower precedence than `!=` operator. So what you have is equivalent to:

```
if ((start_pointer = (strstr(request, "Cookie:") != NULL)){
```

which is basically assign the result of the comparison to `start_pointer`.

However, you don't need to compare with NULL at all (because any non-zero value is "true" in C). You could simply write:

```
if ((start_pointer = strstr(request, "Cookie:"))){
    ...
}
```

or

```
char * start_pointer = strstr(request, "Cookie:");
if (start_pointer) {
    ...
}
```

This way it's much easier to read & helps avoid such mistakes.